# The use of parameter and return in JEST

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

```
it('should call clearSession', result => {
  expect(result).toEqual(put(profileActions.clearSession()));
  return true;
});
```

I am a newbie to JEST and I saw the above in my company project with redux-saga. 
What is the usage of the parameter result and why there is a return statement?

Comment: Are you sure about this code? `result` is a parameter normally called `done`, used to signal to Jest that the test is asynchronous and should wait for `done` to be called before considering the test a pass or fail. For more info: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Comment: I finally found out that it is using the redux-saga-testing package which overrides the it().